# CKeditor - How can I append <article> tags to the editable content body?

Tags: ckeditor

Trying to add `<article>` tag inside the body of CKeditor, so like this:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" src="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" class="cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset" title="Rich Text Editor, editor1" aria-describedby="cke_50" tabindex="0" allowtransparency="true">
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
        <body spellcheck="false" class="cke_editable cke_editable_themed cke_contents_ltr" contenteditable="true">
           <article>  <!-- Add this -->
               <p>Content</p>
           </article>  <!-- Add this -->
        </body>
    </html>
</iframe>
```

Could not find how to get this into the editor. Any tips on how to go about this?

Comment: Would that satisfy you if that tag was added in editor output data only?

Comment: That would defeat the purpose of a WYSIWYG editor; would like the editor body to look exactly the same as the output on the frontend using the same stylesheet.

Comment: Why don't you use [inline editing](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_inline) then?

Comment: It's for the layman / users without HTML knowledge. Would be a hassle to add `<article>` tags to the editor body everytime.